Check Array Contains A Property and Bind It To A New Array
I've an array that I am binding as follows:
const newdata = json.map((c) => {
   return {
     "User Name": c.userName,
     Email: c.email,
     Groups: c.newArrGroups.map(a => a.name).toString(),
     Version: c.clientVersion
   };
});

The above json data is passed from a function, now I've a requirement to check if the array has specific properties. So I found something that can check the properties as follows:
json.hasOwnProperty("userName")

I've two things to verify now. One - Have to check if specific property is in the array and if the property doesn't exist, then remove it from there; Second - There could be arrays inside an array object. Is there any solution with the above that I can check something as follows:
const newdata = json.map((c) => {
  return {

    if(json.hasOwnProperty("userName")) {
      "User Name": c.userName, //To check if property exists, then bind it here
    }

    Email: c.email,

    if(json.newArrGroups.hasOwnProperty("name")) {
      Groups: c.newArrGroups.map(a => a.name).toString(), //This checking is required as well as there would be arrays inside an array object
    }
    
    Version: c.clientVersion
  };
});


Can you provide a demo, maybe stackblitz

just a basic problem here. I have demonstrated it here.


// Sample JSON data
const json = [
    {
        userName: "JohnDoe",
        email: "john.doe@example.com",
        newArrGroups: [{ name: "Admin" }, { name: "User" }],
        clientVersion: "1.0.0"
    },
    {
        email: "jane.doe@example.com",
        newArrGroups: [{ name: "User" }],
        clientVersion: "1.0.1"
    },
    {
        userName: "Alice",
        newArrGroups: [{ name: "Admin" }],
        clientVersion: "1.0.2"
    }
];

// Mapping function
const newdata = json.map((c) => {
    const result = {};
    if (c.hasOwnProperty("userName")) {
        result["User Name"] = c.userName;
    }

    if (c.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
        result.Email = c.email;
    }

    if (c.hasOwnProperty("newArrGroups") && Array.isArray(c.newArrGroups)) {
        result.Groups = c.newArrGroups.map(a => a.name).toString();
    }

    if (c.hasOwnProperty("clientVersion")) {
        result.Version = c.clientVersion;
    }

    return result;
});

// Display the result on the web page
document.getElementById('output').textContent = JSON.stringify(newdata, null, 2);
<h1>Mapped Data</h1>
<div id="output"></div>



Please try it and let me know if it helps! :)

Looks promising, let me try @PPFromInfy. Thanks a lot.

Please accept and upvote the answer if it helps! :)

Sure, will check in some time :)
